# ROS for Aerial Robotics

Tags: ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Folks,

I am newbie at ROS, I had installed Jade version on Ubuntu15.04 vivid. I follow up the wiki, but Indeed it doesn't make sense for me uptill now. Please any good tutorials for the application of ROS for aerial robotics. Also I need to know the main features of ROS. I have to confess that I don't so much about the benefit of using ROS on Linux, rather than fast what others pros?

Best,
Marwa ElDiwiny

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240899/ros-for-aerial-robotics/) by [marwa eldiwiny](https://answers.ros.org/users/27638/marwa-eldiwiny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What do you mean by aerial robotics? There is mavros for interfacing with Pixhawk/PX4/APM flight modules if that's what you are looking for.

I've only used ROS on Linux because that is the OS it is native to. I've heard that it is less stable on other platforms but I've never tested that.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2016-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0